# Unable to send email by pywin32

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I use pywin32 to send email with Outlook.

However, the email are not received.

Can anyone solve this problem?

```
import time
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'abc@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = "test"
mail.Display()
time.sleep(5)
mail.Send()
```

Comment: sorry, it is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that message submission is asynchronous. Make sure Outlook is running when your code is executed. Also get rid of "sleep" - it does nothing.

Comment: I removed "sleep" but also cannot received the email.

Comment: I did not claim removing "sleep" will fix the problem - I just pointed out that it does nothing. Does it work if Outlook is running at the time?